# How to properly read a file in php/laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Please am reading a ***.Txt*** file file which contains contact list in my application and am using Laravel. Am currently having issues reading the file from my route. This is the error am getting now

```
Call to a member function getRealPath() on null
```

This is what i have in my Controller

```
public function bulk_sms(Request $request){

        $upload = $request->file('contact_file');
        $filePath = $upload->getRealPath();

        $file = fopen($filePath, 'r');
        return fread($file, filesize($file));
        fclose($file);
    }
```

Any assistance please?

Comment: Please am still getting the same error..It's not working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form.

Comment: Yeah..I forgot..Thanks

Comment: It works but this is the new error am getting ```filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given```

Comment: change `filesize($file)` to `filesize($filePath)`

Comment: Hey Mortada, Please am trying to add a ***comma*** to each line of the txt file or seperate each line with a ***comma***. Can you assist please?